# Is this function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $M^2(\Bbb R)$ onto?

Tags: matrices, functions

> Let $f$ be the function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $M^2(\Bbb R)$ (the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries) defined by
>
> $$f(a,b) = \left[\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\b & a\end{array}\right],\quad (a,b\in\Bbb R).$$
>
> Is $f$ onto?

What I got is :

All $a\in\Bbb R$ and let there be a $1\times 1$ matrices then $A =[a] \in M^1(\Bbb R)$ such that $f(A) = a$ is onto.

Answer (score 5):

Check up on the definition of being onto. What can you say about the matrices in the image of $f$? For example, can you find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that
$$f(a,b) = \pmatrix{ 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1}?$$
What about, say
$$\pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ 2 & 1}?$$

Answer (score 5):

Which $(a,b)$ would you put through $f$ to get, for example, to $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]\hspace{5pt}?$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've edited your post to preserve the intended meaning. I'm not sure what your proof is trying to do, though.

In order to show that $f$ is onto, you must show that for **every** $2\times 2$ matrix $B$ with real entries, there exist some $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(a,b)=B$. Is this true (do all $2\times 2$ matrices have that form)?

Comment: i dont think it true for all form of 2x2 matrices. then it would not be onto. yes? ex: f(a,b) = [1 0]/[0 1] is not onto

Comment: Indeed, it is *not* true for all $2\times 2$ matrices, so it is not onto. Your example, though, is a $2\times 2$ matrix that **is** reached by the function. Namely, $$f(1,0)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right].$$ For a counterexample, you'll need to pick a matrix that isn't symmetric, or has different entries on the main diagonal (or both).